# SalesForce rendered to call a javascript function

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Is there a way I can make the rendered attribute call a javascript function? The reason I want it to call a javascript function is that the page I'm using doesn't have a controller so I can't do something like `rendered="{!canRender}"`

I'm using an apex:outputText to display a text and I want this text to be hidden for certain users.

I tried doing the following and non of them worked.

```
rendered="javascript:myfucntion();"
rendered="myfunction();"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with the rendered attribute, but you could use javascript on page load to hide fields which you don't want to display by setting their display style attribute to none.